# Get 'most popular' list in Django

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to get the a list of the most popular `events` by how many `attendees` are in each `'event'`.

**Models**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sub_heading = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def attendees(self):
        return Attendee.objects.filter(event=self)

class Attendee(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='event_attendee')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    profile = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

**Views**

```
def event(request, id):
    ...
    events = Events.objects.all()
    attendees = Attendee.objects.filter(event__in=events).count()
    if attendees > 50:
        popular_events = Event.objects.filter(what should i filter by).annotate(attendees_count=Count('attendees')).order_by('-attendee_count') ???
   # I'm probably going about this the wrong way :\
```

I'd really appreciate some insight into this. What I'm doing isn't working. How to I get a  query of popular events?

Comment: Chris has the correct answer. Note that you can also avoid creating a custom `attendees` model method by specifying a `related_name` keyword argument on your `ForeignKey` field on the Attendee model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#inheritance-and-reverse-relations

Comment: Technically you don't need to even do that, if you're okay with using something like `event_instance.attendee_set.all()`, but yeah, if you want it to be `attendees` you need to specify that as the `related_name`, and then the OP can just use `event_instance.attendees.all()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count

popular_events = Events.objects.annotate(attendee_count=Count('attendee')).filter(attendee_count__gt=50)
```